# how load files, icons, xaml files embedded in the project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg

setting the file as "embedded resource" in the properties works like a char and is simple pload, like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
            .Single(str => str.EndsWith("svgImage.xaml"));

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

but if i change from "embedded resource" to just resource....it don't work anymore, i want load a svg image that i converted to a xaml file, to insert in the resource dictionary of a grid dynamically created in code

any tips?

Comment: What is a content of `svgImage.xaml` ? why it has `xaml` estension when you say that it is `svg` ? Why you think that `xaml` will be still a text  after compilation (and not BAML)?

Comment: I also wonder what svgimage.xaml is.  This sounds rather like it ought to go in a resource dictionary since it's clearly not a picture like a png. Why are you reading it in this way?  It seems rather convoluted.  Why not just a style or usercontrol or whatever references the thing directly?

Comment: @Marcos: Why don't you set the `Build Action` property of the XAML file to `Page` and access the XAML resource using a pack URI as usual? Why do you want to extract it programmatically if you still are adding the XAML resource to a `Grid`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The example for text was wrong, I removed it.
The examples are for files that are placed directly in the project.

**Image:**

Add the image there as **Resource**.

```
MyBitmapImageProperty = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Image.png"));
```

**XAML:**

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyBitmapImageProperty}" />
```